# Ionic: Convert a JSON file to a class or constant during build process

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I’m converting an `Ionic` 1 app to `Ionic` 3. In that `Ionic` 1 app we had a `build` process similar to the `Ionic` 3 one, and we used `gulp` for that. One of the things this process did was read a config.json file and convert it to a `constant`. So we converted something like:

```
{
    "cache_expiration_time": 300000,
    "default_lang": "en",
    ...
}
```

to this:

```
angular.module('mm.core').constant('mmCoreConfigConstants', {
    "cache_expiration_time" : 300000,
    "default_lang" : "en",
    ...
});
```

The reason is that we wanted to be able to access these constants synchronously from anywhere, without having to create a service to read the file and parse it.

I’d like to do the same in `Ionic` 3, maybe creating a class that I can import where I want to use it. I’ve been reading a lot of documentation about the `Ionic` `build` process, and I don’t see a clear way to do it. I think the `package.json`'s `config` attribute doesn’t work for me, since my task doesn’t belong to any of the available options.

I thought that maybe I could create my own task (`gulp` or `npm`) to create this “constants” class in my `src` folder before the `Ionic` build process starts, then run the build and, when it’s done, delete this new class from the `src` folder. However, I don’t know how can I add new tasks to the `Ionic` `build` process without having to create my own “npm script” (I’d like to keep using `ionic serve` instead of “npm run whatever”).

Any ideas?

Thanks!